# Hyper-V Guest VM disappeared after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, dell-poweredge

I just rebooted my machine running Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter and on reboot my most crucial VM simply disappeared. I have read this can be due to corruption in the symbolic link or XML file holding the data about the machine, but due to conflicting answers online I don't feel comfortable mucking around in files until I have a more definitive answer. Have any of you experienced this? If so what is the best way to proceed in recovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found that there was a trailing space at the end of the XML configuration file that was causing the errors `</configuration>`. After deleting it it booted back up and everything was back to normal!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have fixed it I was going to suggest creating a new blank VM and then attaching the existing VHDs to the new VM.  this will recreate all the necessary XML files and allow it to boot.  Does not solve the root cause of the problem but if it is a critical machine it may be the quickest solution.